# Proof of Lyapunov Matrix Equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, linear-control

I read the book *A Linear Systems Primer* by Antsaklis, Panos J., and Anthony N. Michel (Vol. 1. Boston: Birkhäuser, 2007) and I am confused by a part of the proof of a theorem about the Lyapunov Matrix Equation.

> \begin{equation} 
> \dot{x}=Ax\tag{4.22} 
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation} 
> C=A^TP+PA\tag{4.25} 
> \end{equation}
>   **Theorem 4.22**. The equilibrium $x = 0$ of (4.22) is stable if there exists a *real,symmetric, and positive definite* $n \times n$ matrix $P$ such that the matrix $C$ given in (4.25) is *negative semidefinite*.
>
> **Proof**. Along any solution $ \phi(t,x_0) \triangleq \phi(t)$ of (4.22) with $\phi(0,x_0)=\phi(0)=x_0$, we have
>
> \begin{equation} 
> \phi(t)^TP\phi(t)=x_0^TPx_0+\int_0^t \frac{d}{d\eta}\phi(\eta)^TP\phi(\eta)d\eta\\
> =x_0^TPx_0+\int_0^t \phi(\eta)^TC\phi(\eta)d\eta \tag{*}
> \end{equation}
>
> for all $t \ge 0$........

So how to obtain (*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of the fundamental theorem of calculus i.e. for an [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) function $f$ on $[0,T]$ we have for $t \in [0,T]$

$$f(t)=f(0)+\int_0^t \frac{d}{dy} f(y) ~dy$$

So in your case for $f(t)=\phi(t)^T P\phi(t)$ we get

\begin{align} \phi(t)^T P\phi(t)&=\phi(0)^T P\phi(0)+\int_0^t \frac{d}{dy} \phi(y)^T P\phi(y) ~dy \\ &=x_0^T Px_0+\int_0^t \frac{d}{dy} \phi(y)^T P\phi(y) ~dy \end{align}